# Explanation of recursive structure of Van Emde Boas Tree

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, algorithm-analysis, search-trees, trees

From [Van Emde Boas trees lecture](http://fileadmin.cs.lth.se/cs/Personal/Rolf_Karlsson/lect12.pdf):

> We will use the idea of superimposing a tree of degree ${u^{1/2}}$ on top of
>   a bit vector, but **shrink the universe size recursively** by a square
>   root at each tree level. The ${u^{1/2}}$ items on the ﬁrst level each hold
>   structures of ${u^{1/4}}$ items, which hold structures of ${u^{1/8}}$ items, and
>   so on, down to size 2.
>   I have a  question regarding van Emde Boas trees :

1. How is the universe size getting reduced ? Aren't we just spreading the universe keys which is always constant at $u$ to different levels ? I can not understand the idea of "**shriniking**" the universe size .  I find similar language is used in defining the recursive structure for Van Emde Boas tree in [Introduction to Algorithms](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-046j-introduction-to-algorithms-sma-5503-fall-2005/) by CLRS also .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well the crucial idea about vEB trees is the following: You store all the elements as a 0/1 bitvector of size $s$. For example the vector $(0,1,1,0)$ denotes that in your universe of size $s=4$, the third and second elements are present. Now you subdivide the vectors in blocks of size $\sqrt{s}$ and for every block you also store a flag, if there is at least one $1$ in the block. This gives you a set of $\sqrt{s}$ flag bits. If you store also the $\min$ and $\max$ for every block, then you can determine in which block you have to continue your search for the successor after **either** perform a successor query in the block of your query element **or** in the flag bit vector.

This implies that the sup-problem you are requesting has size $\sqrt{s}$. But this is the same statement as saying that you go from a $k$-bit universe to a $k/2$-bit universe.

And this is meant by **shrinking** the universe.

Comment: What about my second question ? Would you please clear my doubts on the usage of the word "each " ?

Comment: "f you store also the min and max for every block, then you can determine in which block you have to continue your search for the successor after either perform a successor query in the block of your query element or in the flag bit vector." . can you please explain this point

Comment: I dont get your second question. Regarding your second comment, I advise you to read first about vEB trees, i.e. the wikipedia article. If then something  is unclear, ask a new question. Explaining vEB trees in one answer (that is what you are asking for)  is too broad for this format.

Comment: I am reading up vEB from CLRS book. There they define the proto vEB tree but I didn't find min and max for every block being defined . since every bit vector is a 0 or a 1 , what exadctly you mean by min/max here ?

Comment: @ A.Schulz I have deleted my second question as I understood that concept now .

Comment: @Geek: Exactly! What CLRS calls the proto VEB tree is not a vEB tree. In particular, it is slower.  The difference between proto-vEB tree and vEB-tree is that the former does not store the min/max for every chunk, but the later does. Please continue reading chapter 20.3 of CLRS 3rd edition. Also every bitvector is a sequence of zeros and ones.

Comment: I agree with the previous posters in that the trick is subtle, and not easy to explain in a couple of lines. Erik Demaine's lecture on vEB does I think a very good job of fleshing out what's going on. It can be found [here, with video](http://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.851/spring12/lectures/L11.html); the point most relevant to you is around time 14:00.

Comment: @DanA. Can you summarise the main points, still, maybe in an answer? The link may break and in that case your comment would be left useless.